# How to declare a state variable of type Set()?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, set

I'm trying to create a state variable in React with Typescript. It throws an error when I try to define its type to Set.

This variable is suppose to hold an array of objects.

```
const [blocksList, setBlocksList] = useState<Set>([]);
```

I'm sure I am doing something wrong here but I haven't found any help on internet so far. Please let me know if anyone needs more information on my question. Thanks

Comment: `new Set()` ? ...

Comment: If it's supposed to be an array of objects, then it wouldn't be a `Set`, right?

Comment: @Nick I phrased it wrong. I need a collection of objects to ensure their order, because at some point a user can remove them randomly and I have to make sure it only deletes the selected one not last one.

Comment: Set has nothing to do with order of items in collection

Comment: @KenBekov Set objects are collections of values. You can iterate through the elements of a set in insertion order

Answer (score 3):

`Set` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type.
Here (ctrl + click on a type) we can see that it takes 1 argument.
[image]

You should to pass a type to a Set.
For example:

```
type MyType = { some: string };
const [blocksList, setBlocksList] = useState<Set<MyType>>(new Set());
```

Note: you should to pass in the useState `new Set()` instead `[]`